# Edit HTML documents before they are sent from an express server

Tags: html, node.js, express

This solution is useful when you have very few things that you want to replace on your page, and still want a way to update the page without any HTTP requests or frontend workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need the `Transform` class from the `stream` node library, so add the following to the beginning of your code:

```js
const Transform = require("stream").Transform
```

Then replace

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html")
})
```

with the following:

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const replacementTransform = new Transform()
    replacementTransform._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
        const str = data.toString().replace('anything you want to replace', `whatever you want to replace with`)
        this.push(str)
        done()
    }

    res.write('<!-- Begin stream -->\n');
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('./index.html')
    stream.pipe(replacementTransform)
    .on('end', () => {
        res.write('\n<!-- End stream -->')
    }).pipe(res)
})
```

This will replace any string sequence in your HTML document with anything else you want. The most useful way to use this is to fill the inside of an HTML element by replacing `<p id="empty"></p>` with `<p id="empty">something</p>`.

For larger files, it may be convenient to pipe the file data in chunks instead of as one big piece, which is where a useful library called `new-line` comes in. Simply install it through npm, require it in your file, and replace the current output stream with

```js
res.write('<!-- Begin stream -->\n');
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('./index.html')
    stream.pipe(new-line())
    .pipe(replacementTransform)
    .on('end', () => {
        res.write('\n<!-- End stream -->')
    }).pipe(res)
```